# Remove border color after item is selected in react-select package

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How to remove border color after item is selected from dropdown list in this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

In below gif image once the item is selected the red color still highlights the control, clicking outside will make the red color to disappear. But how to make it disappear immediately when the item is selected

[Sample Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmn5kzwqx7)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-select` exposes `blur` method which you can use to programmatically manage the state of `react-select`.  [Doc Reference](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#methods)

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  rSelecRef = null;

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        ref={item => (this.rSelecRef = item)}
        defaultValue={flavourOptions[2]}
        options={flavourOptions}
        onChange={() => this.rSelecRef.blur()}
        label="Single select"
        placeholder="Single select 1"
        isClearable
        theme={theme => ({
          ...theme,
          borderRadius: 0,
          color: "green",
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary: "#b90000",
            primary25: "#c9cad0",
            primary50: "#c9cad0"
          }
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

It works for this specific scenario. Here is the link to the updated codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n5vo76r02l

Comment: is it possible to do without using **ref**

Comment: You can try out custom styling options. https://react-select.com/styles